# When is the true end of round (pre-flop, flop, turn, or river)?

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-position

What I would like to know is, on hold'em, lets say, 4 players:

```
P1. Check on 100
P2. Call on 100
P3. Rise 200
P4. Fold
```

My question is, after P4 folds, do P1 and P2 need to "Call/Rise/Fold" to match P3 (and then end that round), or the round ends with P4 therefore, P1 options would be "Check/Bet/Fold" to begin a new round.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only options P1 has are to call, raise, or fold. P1 could only check if he had already matched the highest bet (which he hasn't, because of the raise). P2 then has to call the highest bet, raise it, or fold, for the same reasons.

The fact that P4 folded has no impact on what options P1 and P2 have.

**Edit based on comment:** The round (pre-flop, flop, turn, or river) only ends when (1) only one player is left or (2) all remaining players have matched the highest total bet made during the round. So, if the example you gave was the play after the flop cards were dealt, then the flop round continues until all players call the highest bet or only one player remains. Only then does the river come out.

Comment: thank you very much, that actually did answer my question. Sorry for not specifying the word "Round" I meant it as preflop, flop, turn and river

Comment: Ah, got it; please see my edit above.

Comment: @FelipeZuleta, please just edit next time your question. So we get for everyone a good clear question.

Answer (score 1):

After P4 folds, P1 and P2 has to check or raise P3's bet to continue in the hand, otherwise they have to fold, have it be the flop, turn, or river.

If P1 or P2 raises the hand, P3 would then in turn need to check or raise.

This would keep the round going for as long a it should until all players are equally matched in the pot.

Thus said if either P1, P2 or P3 can't call the raised amount, they would need to call all in and the remaining amount would move into a side-pot.